# How do i get PortletContext in servlet.session.destroy.events

Tags: liferay

Portal: Liferay 6.0

In my portlet i need to maintain an object at the application_Scope so that it will availaible for all the users that login. as a solution i thought PortletContext would be something i should use. Hence i went ahead and stored it in the portletcontext like this

```
PortletContext context = renderRequest.getPortletSession().getPortletContext();
context.setAttribute("attr1", "test");
```

Now when the user logsout i want to manipulate this object from the context, for this i wrote a hook that captures the servlet.session.destroy.events. Here is how the code looks like

```
public class MySessionDestroyAction extends SessionAction {
@Override
public void run(HttpSession session) throws ActionException {
ServletContext context = session.getServletContext();
String temp = (String) context.getAttribute("attr1");
context.
}
}
```

As the above class has the HttpSession object, i can get the servletcontext and not the portlet context, still i tried but i could not get the attribute value that i had set in my portlet.

I thought i should set my object in the Servletcontext and then try, for that i my portlet i modified my code to get the servlet context object from the PortalUtil class like this

```
HttpServletRequest httpReq = PortalUtil.getHttpServletRequest(request);
ServletContext scontext = httpReq.getSession().getServletContext();
scontext.setAttribute("attr1", "test");
```

Even after doing this MySessionDestroyAction class does not get the context attribute. Can anyone explain this behaviour? Also, if this is not the right way to implement can anyone suggest what approach i should use.

Thank you

Comment: What kind of information do you wish to store in this "application context"?